# Whats a quick way to convert an IEnumerable<Foo> to List<Foo> in C# 2.0?

Tags: c#, list, .net-2.0, ienumerable

we all know the slow way:

```
foreach..
```

Comment: Is `foreach` really too slow for your needs?

Comment: I think that a foreach will occur at any time, there is no magic.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The [List constructor is a good bet](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fkbw11z0.aspx).

```
IEnumerable<T> enumerable = ...;
List<T> list = new List<T>(enumerable);
```

Answer (score 5):

How about:

```
IEnumerable<T> sequence = GetSequenceFromSomewhere();
List<T> list = new List<T>(sequence);
```

Note that this is optimised for the situation where the sequence happens to be an `IList<T>` - it then uses `IList<T>.CopyTo`. It'll still be O(n) in most situations, but potentially a much faster O(n) than iterating :) (It also avoids any resizing as it creates it.)

Comment: This constructor copies the enumerated items to the new List, so I doubt it's any faster (and nor could it be). But it's certainly easier.

Comment: @GraemeF: As I noted, it *is* faster if the sequence happens to be an `IList<T>`.

Comment: More generically, ICollection<T>'s CopyTo

Answer (score 3):

You want to use the .AddRange method on generic List.

```
List<string> strings = new List<string>();
strings.AddRange(...);
```

.. or the constructor ..

```
new List<string>(...);
```